# 20% pass through deduction + ~20% solo 401k deduction?

Tags: united-states, taxes, 401k, solo-401k

From what I hear none of the 401k stuff has been modified in the new tax bill

This means SOLO 401ks would still have like 20+% profit contribution maxes, up to the $53k or so upper limit from entity contributions (distinct from employee salary contribution subject to the lower limit)

That coupled with the new 20% pass thru deduction really makes this quite a windfall for people, especially up to 200k-300k income ranges, and not a negligible deduction at higher income ranges

Can anyone confirm? My napkin calculations suggests this can get the effective tax rate waaaay below 20% without any expense deductions or getting crafty (before FICA taxes)